# Counting overlaps between a row-specific date range and a column of dates

Tags: r, date, for-loop, data.table, lubridate

My data frame comprises 3 columns, a grouping factor, `Current_Date`, and `Start_Date` (by definition, `Current_Date` ≥ `Start_Date`; date format is `dmy`), with multiple duplicates of dates in each column and a lag of varying length between them. Some dates overlap between groups, but some don't.

The real data is hundreds of thousands rows long, so my problem is finding an efficient way to assign for each row the `unique` number of overlaps between the entire `Date` column (`by` the grouping factor), and the `seq` of dates defined by the time window (`Start_Date` to `Current_Date`), which is specific for each row.

A dummy data is presented below, with the desired result of added  `Dates_in_range` column, but without the grouping factor, which I don't know how to handle in `for`-loop format
(e.g., there is only one unique date in the window between 21-10-22 and 21-10-22, but three unique dates in the window between 21-10-22 and 28-10-22):

```
       Current_Date Start_Date Dates_in_range
    1   21-10-22    21-10-22    1
    2   26-10-22    26-10-22    1
    3   26-10-22    21-10-22    2
    4   26-10-22    26-10-22    1
    5   26-10-22    21-10-22    2
    6   28-10-22    26-10-22    2
    7   28-10-22    28-10-22    1
    8   28-10-22    21-10-22    3
```

My solution is based on creating two types of lists containing dates, by using `for`-loops, and adding each type as a temporary column into the data table:
first type is identical lists of all dates shared by the entire data set (or a group within it) repeated over all rows in the data table (or a group within it);
second type is row-specific lists, derived from the time window specified by `Current_Date` and `Start_Date`.
I then find an `intersect` between the two list columns for each row, applying another `for`-loop.

A reproducible code is attached below:

```
   library(data.table)
    ## Load the data set
    dt = data.table(Current_Date= c("21-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","28-10-22","28-10-22","28-10-22"), 
                    Start_Date = c("21-10-22","26-10-22","21-10-22","26-10-22","21-10-22","26-10-22","28-10-22","21-10-22"))
    # Specify dates into DMY date format
    library(lubridate)
    dt$Current_Date<- dmy(dt$Current_Date)
    dt$Start_Date <- dmy(dt$Start_Date)
    
    ## Create a list of all current dates within the data set (= Current_Date column)
    Dates_all <- as.list(dt$Current_Date)
    # Add the list as a Dates_all column to the data set
    dt$All_dates <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(dt[, Current_Date])){
    dt$All_dates[[i]] <- Dates_all
    }
    
    ## Create a list of sequences of all possible dates within the date period (from Start_Date to Current_Date) for each row
    Date_window <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(dt[, Current_Date])){
    Date_window[[i]] <- as.list(seq(as.Date(dt[i, Start_Date]), as.Date(dt[i, Current_Date]), by="days"))
    }
    # Add the list as a Date_window column to the data set
    dt$Date_window <- Date_window
    
    ## Add the Dates_in_range column containing the number of dates from Current_Date column, occurring in the row-specific time window
    for (i in 1:length(dt[, Current_Date])){
    dt$Dates_in_range[[i]] <- length(intersect(dt$Date_window[[i]], dt$All_dates[[i]]))
    }
    
    # Cleanup & print
    dt[, c("Date_window","All_dates") := NULL]
    rm(Dates_all, Date_window, i)
    print(dt)
```

I suspect it can be accomplished using `foverlaps` function, but I am not sure how to apply it in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table`, you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(Current_Date= c("21-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","28-10-22","28-10-22","28-10-22"), 
                    Start_Date = c("21-10-22","26-10-22","21-10-22","26-10-22","21-10-22","26-10-22","28-10-22","21-10-22"))

dt[,Dates_in_range := sum(between(dt[,unique(Current_Date)], Start_Date, Current_Date)), 
    by=rownames(dt)]

dt
#>    Current_Date Start_Date Dates_in_range
#> 1:     21-10-22   21-10-22              1
#> 2:     26-10-22   26-10-22              1
#> 3:     26-10-22   21-10-22              2
#> 4:     26-10-22   26-10-22              1
#> 5:     26-10-22   21-10-22              2
#> 6:     28-10-22   26-10-22              2
#> 7:     28-10-22   28-10-22              1
#> 8:     28-10-22   21-10-22              3
```

Comment: Thanks, Ric! The code does seem to solve the problem. However, is there a way to incorporate a grouping factor into the `by` subsetting? (I have now added the grouping into the original question) 
Something like:
`dt$Group <- c("B","A","A","A","A","A","A","B")`
so the `Dates_in_range` value for the 8th observation will be 2 istead of 3?

Comment: In such case you should filter the inner dt, you can use .SD to refer outer dt. It would be: `dt[,Dates_in_range := sum(between(dt[Group ==.SD[,Group], unique(Current_Date)], Start_Date, Current_Date)), 
    by=rownames(dt)]
`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply`:

```
dt[, n := sapply(Start_Date, function(x, y) sum(x <= y), y = unique(Start_Date)), by = Current_Date]
```

or using `frank`:

```
dt[, n := frank(1/as.integer(Start_Date), ties.method = "dense"), by = Current_Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, still using for loops that should work. Basically,
we start off by getting a vector of all possible dates, then define a function that will check whether those dates are within a range defined by a minimum or maximum, then we use a for loop through the dataset to apply that function to each row of the data. Of course, we could use `vapply()` here or something of the like if you prefer vectorization.

```
# get unique dates from all columns
dates <- unique(c(dt$Current_Date, dt$Current_Date)) 

# function to see how many are in a range
n_in_range <- function(d, mn, mx) {
  sum(d <= mx & d >= mn)
}

#for loop 
dt$Dates_in_range <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt$Dates_in_range[i] <- n_in_range(dates, dt$Start_Date[i], dt$Current_Date[i])
}
```

```
dt 
   Current_Date Start_Date Dates_in_range
1:   2022-10-21 2022-10-21              1
2:   2022-10-26 2022-10-26              1
3:   2022-10-26 2022-10-21              2
4:   2022-10-26 2022-10-26              1
5:   2022-10-26 2022-10-21              2
6:   2022-10-28 2022-10-26              2
7:   2022-10-28 2022-10-28              1
8:   2022-10-28 2022-10-21              3
```

Comment: Josh, thanks for your answer! It is more elegant than my demonstration, but the for-loop still remains an issue (the real data set includes hundreds of thousands of rows, and is partitioned into groups; I shall clarify it in the question)

Answer (score 0):

without using grouping

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

dt = data.frame(Current_Date= c("21-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","26-10-22","28-10-22","28-10-22","28-10-22"), 
                Start_Date = c("21-10-22","26-10-22","21-10-22","26-10-22","21-10-22","26-10-22","28-10-22","21-10-22"))
dt %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("_Date"), dmy)) %>% 
  mutate(Dates_in_range = map2_dbl(.x = Start_Date, .y = Current_Date, .f = ~sum(between(x = unique(Current_Date), left = .x, right = .y))))

#>   Current_Date Start_Date Dates_in_range
#> 1   2022-10-21 2022-10-21              1
#> 2   2022-10-26 2022-10-26              1
#> 3   2022-10-26 2022-10-21              2
#> 4   2022-10-26 2022-10-26              1
#> 5   2022-10-26 2022-10-21              2
#> 6   2022-10-28 2022-10-26              2
#> 7   2022-10-28 2022-10-28              1
#> 8   2022-10-28 2022-10-21              3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>